# Is it legal for US Senators to take favours?

Tags: united-states, constitution, senate-rules

Is it mentioned in the US Constitution if taking favours in cash or of any kind from an individual or an organization by a Senator is legal or illegal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comment:

> So, if a senator accepts fully funded foreign trip for his family from the NRA, and then votes in favour for laws favouring gun sales, would that be illegal?

It is legal to accept a fully funded trip to a foreign country.  It is legal to vote the NRA (National Rifle Association) position.  What would not be legal would be for him to tell the NRA that he will only vote their position if they give him a fully funded foreign trip.  This of course is difficult to prove.

There is currently an active case against Senator [Bob Menendez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Menendez) of New Jersey.  A personal friend of his has given him both gifts and campaign contributions over the years.  Senator Menendez has attempted to help his friend by participating in meetings and has used the threat of Senate committee hearings to get information and compel behavior.  Menendez's first trial ended in a hung jury.  It's unclear if he'll be tried again.

Another case is that of [Bill Jefferson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_J._Jefferson).  He actually was convicted.  And it's noteworthy what the main evidence was.  He was recorded taking the bribe and explaining what he would do for it.  Without that, he might not have been convicted.  Even with that, seven of the ten charges against him were thrown out by a later judge.  He's out of prison now.

The legal principle is *quid pro quo*.  To prove bribery, it's not enough to prove that the quid and quo exist.  Prosecutors must prove that the one is for the other (the *pro* is the link between the two).  I.e. the quid and the quo have to be part of the same transaction.

In general, most politicians take a stance on gun rights well before they take money or other favors from the NRA.  Under those circumstances it is unlikely that a quid pro quo could be proven.  It's not enough for circumstances to imply that the one thing was done for the other (a reasonable translation of *quid pro quo*).  It has to be proven directly.

It may help you to think about it if you replace gun rights with some other cause.  Perhaps environmental rights (fully paid trip to view the results of climate change), income inequality (you think there's income inequality in the United States, look at how people live in [insert country here]), or just cute cuddly puppies.  The NRA is an advocacy group.  If you take away its ability to advocate, then you open the door to taking away all other groups' ability to advocate.  And you may find that there are groups with which you have more agreement advocating for positions you like.

**TL;DR**:  it is not illegal for Senators to take favors from people who may be affected by their policies or actions *unless* it can be proven that the one was the result of the other.

Answer (score 5):

There is law in the USA beyond the constitution! Bribery of public officials is covered by federal statute: [18 chapter 11 section 201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/201) and the rest of chapter 11. There will also be state laws, a fair amount of case law, and rules and procedures of the Senate.

The US code outlaws anyone offering something of value to a public official with intent to influence any official act. It also outlaws public officials from soliciting such bribes. ([source](https://bribery.uslegal.com/))

The consitution allows for the President and "civil officers" to be removed from office by the impeachment processes for "treason, bribery or other high crimes and misdemeanours". However Senators are [not civil officers](https://www.lectlaw.com/def/c236.htm)

Thus the *US constitution* does not make bribery of a Senator illegal.

Comment: So, if a senator accepts fully funded foreign trip for his family from the NRA, and then votes in favour for laws favouring gun sales, would that be illegal?

Comment: I am not a lawyer. If you have a specific legal question you should consult one.

Comment: Or at the very least, ask on [Law.SE], where there are lawyers.

Comment: It was, but still... removing this comment in a few minutes